# Hibernate one to many relationship does not provide value for foreign key

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

Its being a while since I don't do Hibernate and I wanted to do some simple example the other day but when I needed to do a one to many relationship the many side doesn't get inserted into the database. This is how the database looked like.

[image]

This are my mappings for the person:

**Java**

```
public class ORMPerson implements Serializable {

private Long uniqueId;
private String firstName;
private String secondName;
private Long fkAddress;
```

**hbm**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-mapping package="orm">
    <class name="orm.ORMPerson" table="PERSON">
        <id name="uniqueId" column="UNIQUE_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>

        <property name="firstName" column="FIRST_NAME"/>
        <property name="secondName" column="SECOND_NAME"/>

        <many-to-one name="fkAddress" class="orm.ORMPerson" column="FK_ADDRESS" cascade="all" not-null="false" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This are the mappings for Address:

**Java**

```
public class ORMAddress implements Serializable {

private Long uniqueId;
private String firstLine;
private String secondLine;
private String postcode;
private Set<ORMPerson> ormPersons;
```

**hbm**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-mapping package="orm">
    <class name="orm.ORMAddress" table="ADDRESS">
        <id name="uniqueId" column="UNIQUE_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>

        <property name="firstLine" column="FIRST_LINE"/>
        <property name="secondLine" column="SECOND_LINE"/>
        <property name="postcode" column="POSTCODE"/>


        <set name="ormPersons" table="ADDRESS" inverse="true" fetch="select" cascade="save-update">
            <key>
                <column name="UNIQUE_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="ORMPerson"/>
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is the client code that I use to insert an address with multiple persons:

```
ORMAddress ormAddress = new ORMAddress();
        ormAddress.setFirstLine(address.getFirstLine());
        ormAddress.setSecondLine(address.getSecondLine());
        ormAddress.setPostcode(address.getPostcode());
        ormAddress.setOrmPersons(ormPersons);


        session.save(ormAddress);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

If I try to call the session.save() method with ormPersons, I will see the data being added to the database, but the foreign kew will have no value. I think this is because I just have a not-null="false" in Person but this is not a solution, I think all should be inserted automatically by just calling once the save method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is hidden in the `inverse="true"` mapping. This is saying to Hibernate:

> when you persist collection - let that job on its items. These items must be aware of their parent.

But as we can see above, the `ormPersons` are not provided with back reference to ormAddress.

```
...
// after that line we have to do more
ormAddress.setOrmPersons(ormPersons);
// we have to assign back reference
for(ORMPerson ormPerson: ormPersons)  {
    ormPerson.setOrmAddress(ormAddress);
}
```

and also we would need ORMAddress reference inside of the ORMPerson - not as LONG

```
public class ORMPerson implements Serializable {
...
private ORMAddress ormAddress;
```

hbm

```
<class name="orm.ORMPerson" table="PERSON">
    ....
    <many-to-one name="ormAddress" class="orm.ORMPerson" 
        column="FK_ADDRESS" cascade="all" not-null="false" />
</class>
```

And finally, many-to-one and one-to-many must use the same column

hbm of Address (FK_ADDRESS):

```
<class name="orm.ORMAddress" table="ADDRESS">
    ...
    <set name="ormPersons" table="ADDRESS" inverse="true" 
         fetch="select" cascade="save-update">
        <key>
            //<column name="UNIQUE_ID" not-null="true" />
            <column name="FK_ADDRESS" not-null="true" /> // the parent id
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="ORMPerson"/>
    </set>
```

Check the doc for an example:

[23.2. Bidirectional one-to-many](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#example-parentchild-bidir)